# Sitecore query how to select an item with a certain parent id

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

I want to select an item whoes parent has id = xx.

I am using this query:

```
 var mainSectionItem =
            Sitecore.Context.Item.Axes.SelectSingleItem("./ancestor::*[@@parentid = '{E3C35E4C-B3D9-4153-B53E-E4004E76D768}']");
```

But I get null. In the above code when I change `@@parentid` to `@@id` then I get the MainItem. Just for clarification this is what I am doing:

- MainItem [id={E3C35E4C-B3D9-4153-B53E-E4004E76D768}]

  - A

    - A1
    - A2
  - B

    - B1
    - B2

From A1 or A2 I want to get A and if context item is B1 or B2 I want to get item B. This is just an example, the tree can be more deeper.

Comment: @@parentid is not a valid attribute.. can't you use templatename (or id)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember the correct Xpath syntax, but maybe something like:

`"./../[./../../[@id = '{E3C35E4C-B3D9-4153-B53E-E4004E76D768}']]"`

`./../ <-- one step up ( A / B )`
Use the [] as an "if statement",

```
[./../..] - A1/A/MainItem[Who has X as ID]
```

So basicly, Select current Nodes parent, if current nodes parents parent is X.

the syntax is properly off, but the mindset might help. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

As Gatogordo says in the comments, the Sitecore Query language doesn't have a special attribute for `@@parentid`. You can use `parent::` as an axis, but it behaves oddly compared to what you'd expect from XPath, so I tend to avoid it.

The valid options for matching the core attributes of an item I'm aware of are:

[image: Valid options]

The most common pattern for "find an appropriate parent item" is probably finding the right item based on its template. Finding things by their template makes your code more flexible - it keeps working if the specific items get destroyed and re-created (which would change their IDs) and also if new content is created with the same templates.

Your query is probably something like `ancestor::*[@@templateid='{template-guid-for-A-here}' or @@templateid='{template-guid-for-B-here}']` - though that assumes A and B have different templates. If they both have the same template you can remove the second `@@templateid` clause. (Alternatively you can also use `@@templatename` here if you prefer) You could also use the `ancestor-or-self::` axis here if you wanted the query to work on the A&B items as well as Ax&Bx.